# uso de bat en busqueda de palabra clave

Tags: csv, batch

Por favor si alguien me indica como hacer un cambio dentro de un archivo de extencion csv, mediante un bat, digo si dentro del archivo csv tengo partes escritas ejemplo:

```
Hlmm.dds 32 image.jpg
```

Quiero que el bat solo ubique el texto hlmm y lo cambie por gfmm y que este dentro del archivo .csv solo alle cambiado dicho texto sin eliminar ni modificar el resto de la linea escrita. Y que conserve su extencion original .csv y quede asi:

```
gfmm.dds 32 image.jpg
```

Nota: la extencion csv originalmente es de libre ofice (hoja de calculo). pero tambien se abre con editores de texto, me iteresa que conserve su caracter de celda divisorio que es la coma. Por defauld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%3" == "" goto ayuda
set cadorig=%1
set cadorig=%cadorig:"=%
set cadsust=%2
set cadsust=%cadsust:"=%
for %%f in (%3) do (call :cambiar %%f)
goto fin
:cambiar
set archivo=%1
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in (%archivo%) do (set ANT=%%i&echo   !ANT:%cadorig%=%cadsust%! >>kk_temp.txt)
copy /y kk_temp.txt %archivo%
del /q kk_temp.txt
goto :EOF
:Ayuda
Echo Reemplaza una cadena por otra en el contenido de archivos (con comodines)
echo Utiliza un archivo temporal kk_temp.txt que no debe existir previamente
echo Formato: %0 cadorig cadsust archivos
echo Si las cadenas contienen espacios deben escribirse entrecomilladas
echo No funciona si la cadena original contiene un "="
Echo Ejemplo:
echo %0 de DE *.txt
:Fin
```

USO

> sustituye.bat Hlmm "gfmm" C:\prueba\miarchivo.csv